# Default WPF Styles with local Styles

Tags: wpf, styles

I have a default style for TextBlocks. However, if I supply another style template that, say, only changes the foreground, and set that style on my TextBlock, it appears that all of the settings in the default style are lost. What's the best way around that where I can still make use of the default style?

By default, I mean `<Style x:Key={x:Type TextBlock} TargetType={x:Type TextBlock}>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Style.BasedOn property. It will allow your Style to inherit properties from the Style it is BasedOn without having to recreate the entire style. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Aah. Thank you. Looked at BasedOn many times but was specifically missing this: BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}"